# Codeigniter search function throws an error

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I have written some code to make a search in the CODEIGNITER3 framework. When I insert 2 or more words to search input, it works great, however, when I enter just 1 word, it gives this error.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?
Here is my controller:

```
function search() {
            $keyword = strip_tags($this->input->get('searchforcourses'));
            $keyword = explode(" ", $keyword);

            $data['title'] = 'Bütün Kurslar Burada';
            $data['courses'] = $this->courses_model->courses_search($keyword);


            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('courses/courses', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

And here is my model:

```
function courses_search($keyword) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('courses');
            $this->db->like('title',$keyword[0]);
            $this->db->or_like('title',$keyword[1]);
            $this->db->join('instructors', 'instructors.id = courses.instructor_id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = courses.category_id', 'left');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know for sure that the `$keyword` array contains two values?

Comment: @MehdiBounya the problem is, I want to check it, but do not know how

Comment: Why are you even bothering with checking how many values the array contains? why don't you just loop through the `$keyword` array and use the `or_like` method inside the loop?

Comment: As I am new, I did not get your idea :( Can you explain please briefly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you are trying to access an unexisting key `1`, your code is wrong on the model level, your code is only getting two keywords, what if the user searched for three keywords? are you just going to ignore them?

I suggest doing it like this:

```
function courses_search($keyword) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('courses');
    // You should consider limiting the number of keywords to avoid long loops
    // Limits to 20 keywords
    $keyword = array_slice($keyword, 0, 19);
    // You can also limit it in the 3rd parameter of the explode function
    // Loop through the keywords
    forearch($keyword as $key){
        $this->db->or_like('title',$key);
    }
    $this->db->join('instructors', 'instructors.id = courses.instructor_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = courses.category_id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```